# Highcharts tooltip bug with stacked column chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

There seems to be an issue with displaying stacked charts with multiple series, where the series don't have the same number of points.

**JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/k68pwbm7/1/**

```js
$(function () {
        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'column'
            },
            tooltip: {
                shared: true
            },
            plotOptions: {
                column: {
                    stacking: 'normal'
                }
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'John',
                data: [500, 30, 400, 70, 2,500, 30, 400, 70, 2]
            }, {
                name: 'Jane',
                data: [200, 2000, 30, 200, 1,200, 2000, 30, 200]
            }, {
                name: 'Joe',
                data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5]
            }]
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Look at point at **X=6** (tall column), if you mouse over the column at **Y<500**, a tooltip shows up for **X=4**, which is the last point for the **"Joe"** series. Then if you mouse over the same column at **y>500** the correct tooltip shows up with just the two series for that column.

Is this a known issue? Any way to fix this?

Comment: The only workaround seems to make tooltip: {       
           shared: false            
        } and stickyTracking false. But if you need shared tooltip , need to dig more into it. Also you series not have same number of points so better if you off shared property

Comment: See the fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/k68pwbm7/2/

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but definitely need shared tooltip. My actual chart has 7 different series stacked. Having to mouse over each piece separately is not user-friendly.

Comment: The issue is already fixed in github version of Highcharts (next release candidate) - JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/k68pwbm7/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading to `Highcharts 4.1.10` fixed the issue for me.